# Index data with php crawlers to ElasticSearch

Tags: php, web-crawler, elasticsearch

I want to index crawled websites to ElasticSearch but i don't know can i index crawled information to ElasticSearch with php crawler. I know that Apache nutch can index crawled websites to ElasticSearch but i don't know anything about php crawlers!
Is there any php crawler that it's performance good and can index crawled websites to ElasticSearch?
Help me to choose php crawler for my project that i can integrate it with ElasticSearch.
Can i use Apache nutch with php web application?

Answer (score 2):

Check it out :

- [PHPCrawl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpcrawl/files/PHPCrawl/)
- [Korotkin-Solutions/PHP-Crawler](https://github.com/Korotkin-Solutions/PHP-Crawler)
- [OrphanCrawler](https://github.com/Ultrabenosaurus/OrphanCrawler)

I suppose, the best it's to use PHP crawler, as You could control index private content and detect modifications more precisely.